# Access a file outside the current folder in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a module for routing in Node.js inside a folder in the main server, like this.

```
+root.js (server main)
+modulos (folder where rutas.js is)
    ++rutas.js
+shalimar (folder where all the static files are)
    ++muestrame.html (I want to send this)
```

My code looks like:

```js
root.js (main server)

var express = require('express');
var router_app = require('./modulos/rutas');

web.listen(4200, function() {
    console.log('Servidor Web Iniciado en el Puerto : 4200');
});

web.use(express.static(__dirname + '/shalimar'));

web.use('/app', router_app);
```

Here I call rutas.js inside modulos

```js
rutas.js (inside modulos)

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (entra, sale) => {
    console.log('Cargando desde routing.js');
    sale.sendFile('/shalimar/muestrame.html', {root : __dirname});
});
```

This error gets thrown:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\Eleazar Ortega\desktop\uneweb\modulos\shalimar\muestrame.html'

My question is how to level up (outside modulos) in the folder to access `shalimar/muestrame.html`

Comment: If the source file is not in the project, maybe you have to specify his path gloabally given the hierarchy of your file system, rather than using a relative path

Answer (score 4):

Well yes, `__dirname` is the value of the current folder, so it is still relative to `modulos`. You'd have to store that value to a variable and pass it through from the index file in the root.

Why not just do `'../shalimar/muestrame.html'`?

Or even better `path.resolve('../shalimar/muestrame.html')`

Comment: There's no reason to use `path.normalize()`.

Comment: No harm in it, to make sure there are no inconsistencies between operating systems. Perhaps `path.resolve()` instead. The express core code doesn't seem to use either within `sendFile` itself, but does wrap filenames being sent into it in a `path.resolve()`

Comment: There are no OS inconsistencies with `../xxx`.

Comment: Forward/backward slashes between Unix/Windows though, surely?

Comment: So, now you're saying that every path name you use in node.js programming should be put through `path.normalize()`?  Just curious if you think that is required?

Comment: Well, I think really I mean resolve, not normalize. No, it's not always required. But often people run into issues because of not using it at all. Perhaps you're sending the value to another script which doesn't understand the current directory. It's also very good for debugging because you can `console.log` out the result and see what path it's attempting to reach.